# 4K video (50 Frames/Second) using ReactPlayer not playing on Chrome (desktop or mobile)

Tags: html, reactjs, video, web-deployment, media

On a website we have developed, we are using react player and have come across a strange issue.
Videos which are 4K quality at 50 Frames a second do not play on Chrome on Desktop/Laptop or mobiles. The videos do play on Chromium edge and Safari, albeit do take a while to buffer.
We have tried to use alternates to react player, but are not able to find a solution here, the issue is clearly something that Chrome is not liking but obviously we cannot ask all our clients to make individual changes to their browsers.
The only error we see on the Laravel backend is ERR_CACHE_OPERATION_NOT_SUPPORTED, but not sure if this is related.
Has anyone got any ideas and any possible solution?

Thanks
Jit

Comment: I'm assuming the videos are MP4 since you tried to play them on Safari. **(1)** Check the codecs in the MP4 using a tool like **MediaInfo** or a player like **VLC** (check its options/menus for codec info). Basically if the video codec inside is H.265 then your MP4 won't work in Chrome. **(2)** Slow start might be due to your metadata being at back of file (so waiting for byte stream to reach it before playback begins). You can check by opening your smallest file (in bytes size) with a **hex editor**. If you don't see `moov` on the first 2 or 3 lines, then your metadata is at back of file.

Comment: Hi Many thanks for your reply. Indeed the videos are mp4, and they are H.265, many thanks for pointing out that it's not compatible with chrome.  Thanks to your answer, we have come up a work around to identify the codec type using some javascript, then run a conversion using free tool ffmpeg to h.264, parameters we used to convert  was i <input_video> -vcodec libx264 -preset slow -crf 22 <output_video>. There is no apparent drop off in quality to the naked eye, so this solution works for us until chrome will support h.265.

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with react, and is purely determined by the codecs supported by the browsers you're deploying to. Figure _that_ part out first. Use any of a million tools to determine which codec and settings your videos use, and use `ffmpeg` to convert them to a format, codec, and settings that are known to work for each (or all) browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comment by VC.One, a solution to this is identify the codec type using some Javascript [like this example code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71914018/2057709), then run a conversion using free tool ffmpeg to h.264, parameters we used to convert was:

```
-i <input_video> -vcodec libx264 -preset slow -crf 22 -movflags +faststart <output_video>
```

There is no apparent drop off in quality to the naked eye, so this solution works for until Chrome will support h.265